# References for a tenure track position

Tags: tenure-track, assistant-professor, anthropology

I am going to apply for a position as assistant professor (anthropology) and I have a question regarding the references I have to present. Should they all be from professors? One of my references is a laboratory coordinator and in charge of department collections (permanent position but not professor). He knows very well how I work, better even than professors who could write the reference letter, but would talk about me in a more generic way. What would be a better option?

Comment: You’re applying for a position as a professor. With rare exceptions, go for letters from professors (exception examples: you can’t find 3 to recommend you w/o reservation, you come from industry). You really don’t want to be recommended by a lab administrator not involved in research and teaching, if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of the position, actually. For most people the important aspects of the job are teaching, research, and service (in some order of importance). If the third person can support any of those, or any particular aspect of the position not covered by them, then it would be fine.

Otherwise, it would be better to align your letters with the nature of the job.

However, you also need people who know you well and can say positive things about how you will fit the position. You should choose the best among them.

Comment: '...say positive things' -- this part of the process is quite meaningless in a way.  Who would include negative letters?  Usually, referees who would say something negative will not accept to be a referee to ensure a person finds a job.

Comment: @VitaminE, it isn't necessary to be negative. A non-committal or neutral letter can be devastating. "The candidate took my course and did well."

Comment: I wouldn't offer to write a neutral letter for exactly the reason you pointed out.